# Grouping MCU pin connections

Tags: microcontroller, pcb-design, adc, gpio

I'm trying to decide on pin mapping (forgive me if this is the wrong term) for a PIC32MZ1024EFF100, but this isn't something I've ever done before.

There are 32 GPIOs and 8 Analog inputs that need to be connected.  I want to ensure they are connected to the optimal pins of the MCU, but I don't know how to tell what is optimal.

For groups of connections that share similar functions, should I:

- Connect them to pins that are physically close to each other?
- Connect them to pins that share the same register inside the PIC?
- Or is there something else I should be considering instead?

Comment: It depends what the signals are and what you need them for. For example analog signals must go to pins that can be read as analog.

Comment: Signals that must connect to specific peripherals (i.e. SPI, I2C, UART, etc) might also have to go to a specific pin, or at least to one of a subset of pins.

Comment: Yes, that much is clear.  My question is more about the arrangement of the pins:  for my 8 analog signals for example, should I try really hard to put them all right next to each other (using eg pins 18-25), or should I try hard to keep them far apart, with two on every side of the device?

Comment: @Infinite_Maelstrom Why do you think the analog signals might better be separated?

Comment: That depends on if the analog signals can disturb each other or not. Or if they are sensitive so they get disturbed by digtal signals. You really don't give any reasons to do it in a specific way because of some reason.

Comment: It is unlikely that the analog signals will disturb each other in this design, they will be changing very slowly (no more than 3V/sec).  I will want to keep the GPIO outs away from everything since they'll be PWM, but that isn't a strong enough constraint to answer my question.

Comment: Well that is a key part, PWM can disturb other digital and analog signals, especially those which have relatively high impedance. Any other fast signals? And what to do with the signals just depends on how they relate, if any. For example if you have 8 buttons and a LED for each button, you could have 8 inputs and 8 outputs, or group button and matching LED next to each other. But then it depends on if you need special pin features like pin change interrupt etc that may only be available on specific pins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case there are no critical EMC or high speed signal issues, then normally the software engineer is allowed to dictate which pins to use and group them as per how the GPIO peripheral port registers are defined in the MCU. That is, your option "Connect them to pins that share the same register inside the PIC"

If you for example have some 8 bit "port x" register and mean to use 8 pins for a related purposes in software - lets say parallel input from an external 8 bit dip-switch or shift register - then you would use the pins corresponding to "port x", no matter where they happen to be located on the package.

The MCU manufacturer has already made internal EMC considerations regarding analog, digital and clock parts, usually keeping the oscillator pins or timer/PWM pins away from the analog pins etc.

Now in case you have sensitive signals like some high speed bus, high resolution analog signals, bit-banging to/from a RFIC or similar, then the PCB designer should be the one deciding which pins to use and the software designer has to adapt accordingly. Such signals should be given top priority in the PCB layout overall, which normally means keeping the traces as straight and short as possible, avoiding vias if possible etc.

Answer (score 5):

**Where** you have options, you can give some thought to physical connections if you expect layout to be gnarly, or you can give some thought to logical arrangement if you expect to need to wring the last bit of speed out of the MCU, but often these days it's not so important - we often have luxurious amounts of speed and potential layout density (and you can always go back and revise it later if necessary- non-trivial design is typically *iterative*).

Generally, I think optimizing the logical connections make more sense even if it's a bit harder on the layout dude (and even if the layout dude happens to be you). Of course there will be exceptions (for example, you might be cramming a chip into a narrow housing and you can't even use some of the pins realistically).

And don't forget to make the schematic easy to read (start with that) and document design decisions, perhaps by separating the pins in blocks into different schematic symbols if there are a plethora of them. That will minimize the potential issues with communicating with the firmware dude (even if that dude happens to be you) and for potential future revisions  (you might be surprised by how much gets forgotten in a few short years with many projects inbetween).

Although links to external 'answers' are frowned upon here, I would suggest seeking out the video tutorials of people such as Robert Feranec and Phil Salmony and following many of their recommendations on creating both schematics and layouts. There is far more to this than can be contained in a dozen suitable-length answers here.

Comment: In your middle paragraph, by "Logical connections," do you mean connections to the internal logic of the chip (what I termed in my question as "connecting to pins that share the same register") or something else?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. So if you have LEDs 1..5 to drive you might use RB0..4 rather than some hodgepodge of different registers and pins. And maybe rename the LEDs 0..4 to keep things consistent.